# What is the fastest way to download files and add them to a gridview?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to download a text file which contains a lot of domains:

```
    private void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // backgroundworker
        string action = e.Argument as string;
        if (action == "xc_download")
        {
            // this downloads the daily domains from the main site

            // format the date to append to the url
            DateTime theDate = DateTime.Now;
            theDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            string downloadURL = String.Empty;
            downloadURL = ("http://www.namejet.com/Download/" + (theDate.ToString("M-dd-yyyy") + ".txt"));

            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                string urls = wc.DownloadString(downloadURL);
                dgView.Rows.Add(urls);
            }

        } // if (action == "xc_download")
    }
```

Once downloaded, I'm trying to add them to a datagrid. The problem is, this is very very slow. Is there a faster way to download text files and add **the data** to the gridview I should be using?

Comment: what is "a lot" of domains?

Comment: And what exactly is slow? How many `BackgroundWorker`s do you have? How big are the files? Would a faster internet connection help? Also, adding rows to a UI object is a bad idea from a `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: Hey guys, this is a sample: http://www.namejet.com/Download/5-07-2014.txt, i just have 1 backgroundworker running, i'm trying to add each url (from the .txt file) in to the gridview, i know it's not  agood idea but i used CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false; to send to the UI.

Comment: thats not only a bad idea it ends up in untracable errors. Don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could parallelize the download process. One option is TPL's [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783747(v=vs.110).aspx). You can set the maximum number of concurrent actions (downloads) to prevent the servers from being flooded.

```
List<string> downloads = new List<string>();
downloads.Add(...);

Parallel.ForEach
( downloads
, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8 } /* max 8 downloads simultaneously */
, url => Download(url)
);
```

Then create a download method and handle the downloading in there:

```
private void Download(string url)
{
    // download

    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
    {
        // update the UI inside here
    });
}
```